# Adding the items in a list within a list to find the average

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Okay so I have a list within a list(inception like madness) and it looks like this....

```
list = [[62.0, 0.07427184466019418, 9, 0.6058252427184466, 0.07455501618122977, 0.0634304207119741, 0.12637540453074433, 0.4357200647249191, 0, 0, 45], [98.0, 0.32406580793266165, 16, 1.9099604642265018, 0.5279938783318454, 0.19997449304935594, 3.547506695574544, 1.3736768269353399, 0, 0, 35]]
```

What I'm trying to do is find the average of each item.
So in the above lists i'd add 62.0 + 98.0(62 + 98 are the first items in each list) and divide by two to find the average.

I was thinking something like this...

```
for row in list:

        counter = + 1
        row[0] = row[0] + row[0] / under_total
```

Any suggestions would be very welcome. I hope this makes sense, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = [[62.0, 0.07427184466019418, 9, 0.6058252427184466, 0.07455501618122977, 0.0634304207119741, 0.12637540453074433, 0.4357200647249191, 0, 0, 45], [98.0, 0.32406580793266165, 16, 1.9099604642265018, 0.5279938783318454, 0.19997449304935594, 3.547506695574544, 1.3736768269353399, 0, 0, 35]]

answer = []
for col in zip(*L):
    answer.append(sum(col)/len(col))
print(answer)
```

Output:

```
[80.0, 0.1991688262964279, 12.5, 1.2578928534724743, 0.30127444725653757, 0.131702456880665, 1.8369410500526442, 0.9046984458301295, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0]
```

If you have non-numeric entries in your lists:

```
answer = []
for col in zip(*L):
    col = [c for c in col if isinstance(c, int) or isinstance(c, float)]
    answer.append(sum(col)/len(col))
print(answer)
```

If it is indeed possible to have a column full of non-numeric values, then it is possible for you to run into a ZerDivisionError. So let's say that in those cases, you want to say that the average is `0`. Then this should do the trick:

```
answer = []
for col in zip(*L):
    col = [c for c in col if isinstance(c, int) or isinstance(c, float)]
    if col:
        answer.append(sum(col)/len(col))
    else:
        answer.append(0)
print(answer)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. Would you know what to do if there was two item in the list that are not numbers. how would you slip these? my list looks like this [74, 0.1423287845938018, None, None, 10, 1.9099604642265018, 0.5185563065935468, 1.6825659992347914, 3.547506695574544, 2.7789822726693023, 20051, 0, 25, None' >50K']

Comment: @DerekMcAuley: check out the edit. That should take care of any non-numeric entries

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting a "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero" error

Answer (score 1):

Built-in `zip` function is for this job:

```
>>> s
[[62.0, 0.07427184466019418, 9, 0.6058252427184466, 0.07455501618122977, 0.0634304207119741, 0.12637540453074433, 0.4357200647249191, 0, 0, 45], [98.0, 0.32406580793266165, 16, 1.9099604642265018, 0.5279938783318454, 0.19997449304935594, 3.547506695574544, 1.3736768269353399, 0, 0, 35]]
>>> [(i + j) / 2 for i, j in zip(s[0], s[1])]
[80.0, 0.1991688262964279, ...]
```

We can even generalise it to arbitrary number of sublist:

```
>>> [sum(l)/len(l) for l in zip(*s)]
[80.0, 0.1991688262964279, 12, 1.2578928534724743, 0.30127444725653757, 0.131702456880665, 1.8369410500526442, 0.9046984458301295, 0, 0, 40]
```